# Help understanding definition of homeomorphism (isomorphisms in topological spaces)

Tags: general-topology, definition

Definition 2.4.6 of the book *Topology An Introduction* by Stefan Waldmann states the following:

> Let $f:(M, \mathcal{M}) \longrightarrow(N, \mathcal{N})$ be a map between topological spaces.
>
> - $f$ is called a homeomorphism if $f$ is bijective, continuous, and if $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
> - If there is a homeomorphism $f:(M, \mathcal{M}) \longrightarrow(N, \mathcal{N})$ then the spaces $(M, \mathcal{M})$ and $(N, \mathcal{N})$ are called homeomorphic.
> - $f$ is called an embedding if $f$ is injective and if
>   $$f:(M, \mathcal{M}) \longrightarrow\left(f(M),\left.\mathcal{N}\right|_{f(M)}\right)$$
>   is a homeomorphism

What confuses me in the above definition is the last point. In the definition of $f$ the input is a topological space $(M,\mathcal{M})$, but in the last point it seems the input is a set $M$. Also, what does the notation $\left.\mathcal{N}\right|_{f(M)}$ mean?

Comment: The last codomain is the image of $f$ given the subspace topology inherited from $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $\left.\mathcal{N}\right|_{f(M)}$ is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) of the topology $\cal N$ on $f(M)$, defined by
$$
\left.\mathcal{N}\right|_{f(M)} = \{ U \cap f(M) \mid U \in {\cal N}\}
$$
Thus $\left(f(M), \left.\mathcal{N}\right|_{f(M)}\right)$ is a well-defined topological space.

Comment: Not really: $f(M)$ is a set, and it is equipped with the topology induced by $\cal N$. It would be a serious abuse of notation to write that $f(M) = f(M, {\cal M})$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition says that an injective map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is an embedding if upon the set theoretic identification between $M$ and $f(M)$ the topology on $M$ coincides with that induced by $N$.

This doesn't necassarily happen. I believe that the standard example of an injective continuous map which is not an embedding is injecting the open interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ in such a way that
$\lim_{t\to1}f(t)=f(1/2)$ (Concretely bend an open segment in such a way its final part gets arbitrarily close to its midpoint).

Comment: In the given definition, $f$ is required to be a homeomorphism. Is it the case with your example?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: An embedding is an homeomorphism between a space and its image endowed with the topology induced by the target space. In "my" example this doesn't happen because the open intervals centered in $1/2$ are not open sets in the topology induced by $\Bbb R^2$.